# How to install Joomla in subfolder where Wordpress is installed in web root

Tags: .htaccess-configuration

I have Wordpress installed at `example.com`.

I did have Joomla 3 installed at `example.com/joomla`.

Now `example.com/joomla` loads a Wordpress 404 for some reason.

Even `example.com/joomla/index.php` loads a Wordpress 404.

I can see the Joomla files are intact in the `/joomla` folder, and `configuration.php` contains the correct db details. I can see in `phpMyAdmin` the db is intact.

When I checked `.htaccess` in the `/joomla` folder it was called `htaccess.txt`. Renaming this to `.htaccess` did not resolve the problem.

How can I ensure the Joomla 3 website runs properly again from a sub-directory where Wordpress is installed in the root domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the Joomla folder from WordPress's rewrite rules. In the WordPress .htaccess you would exclude /joomla

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule for more information